# Is "other" singular and "others" plural?

Tags: word-choice, word-difference, plural-forms

I was asked this question today, but I am unsure how to answer that.

Why is

> “These others books.”

incorrect but

> "This other book."

is correct?  I thought other is singular and others is plural.

Comment: Adjectives in English do not have any marking that indicates grammatical number.  The *other* dog. The *other* dogs.   The *big* tree.  The *big* trees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other is used both as a noun, and as an adjective.

When using Other as an adjective to describe an object (the "other book"), it will always be used without the s.

However, when using other as a noun identifying the object itself then we have to get the case right -

- I want to read all these books, and the others.
- The red book and the other are both heavy